# How do you use grep to find a pattern in a file, EDIT IT with awk (or some other thing), and then save it?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, tr

I need to edit specific lines in a text file. I have a pattern here, `pattern.txt`:

```
1
3
6
17
etc...
```

and a file with text, `file.txt`:

```
1 text
2 text
3 text
4 text
5 text
etc...
```

I want to add the words `_PUT FLAG HERE` to the end of each line of `file.txt` on lines that have match indicated by the `pattern.txt`.

I have

```
grep -F -f pattern.txt file.txt | awk '{print $0 "_PUT FLAG HERE" }'
```

But I can't seem to figure out a way to *shove* those changes back into the original file so it looks like this:

```
1 text_PUT FLAG HERE
2 text
3 text_PUT FLAG HERE
4 text
5 text
6 teeskjtkljeltsj _PUT FLAG HERE
etc...
```

It's a lot like trying to use `tr`, but much more convoluted. There should be a logical way to string AWK and grep, I just can't seem conceive of a way to put the pieces together into one pipe that would do this, and I can't find the answer anywhere. (If you explain a sed way to do this, please explain the regex.)

Comment: If you're using awk, you can stop using grep. Almost everything that grep can do, awk can also do. No need for extra pipe fitting. That said, can you perhaps include some meta code that describes the logic of how you're envisioning this should work? I'm not getting it from your description.

Comment: See the third block of gray  text? I  need it to look like that. See how pattern.txt has the number 1 and 3 in it? It's telling me I need to edit the line with the number 3 or 1 in it and append the string PUT_FLAG_HERE at the end of those patterns that match pattern.txt

Comment: Never use the word "pattern" as it is highly ambiguous. Please edit your question to replace the word "pattern" with "string" or "regexp" (whichever one you mean by "pattern") everywhere it's currently used and include in your sample input/output partial match cases (e.g. `3` in `pattern.txt` and `137` in `file.txt`) so we can see how you want partial matches handled. Also include cases like `99 foo3bar` in `file.txt` so proposed solutions that don't look in the correct column for `3` will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's#.*#/&/s/$/_PUT FLAG HERE/#' pattern.txt | sed -f - file
```

This turns the pattern file into a sed script which is then invoked against the text file.

Comment: Shouldn't this anchor at the start of the line to avoid partial matches?

Comment: For some reason the other answers didnt work, but this one miraculously worked. I will select it as the right answer, thank you potong!

Comment: Also, would you mind explaining to me what's going on in all those symbols? I want to be able to add this skill set, but I'm unable to comprehend the combination of symbol operations because I am not used to using sed

Answer (score 3):

Assume your awk has been taken hostage.

A GNU sed/grep solution! To generate a sed script that does what you want, we get the lines to change from the input file:

```
$ grep -wFf pattern.txt file.txt
1 text
3 text
6 text
17 text
```

This matches complete words (`-w`) so `1 text` is matched, but `11 text` is not; `-F` is for fixed strings (no regex, should be faster) and `-f pattern.txt` reads the patterns to look for from a file.

Now we pipe this to sed to generate a script:

```
$ grep -wFf pattern.txt file.txt | sed 's#.*#/^&$/s/$/_PUT FLAG HERE/#'
/^1 text$/s/$/_PUT FLAG HERE/
/^3 text$/s/$/_PUT FLAG HERE/
/^6 text$/s/$/_PUT FLAG HERE/
/^17 text$/s/$/_PUT FLAG HERE/
```

The sed command in the pipe matches the complete line (`.*`) and assembles an address plus substitution command (`&` stands for the whole previously matched line).

Now we take all that and use it as input for sed by means of process substitution (requires Bash):

```
$ sed -f <(grep -wFf pattern.txt file.txt | sed 's#.*#/^&$/s/$/_PUT FLAG HERE/#') file.txt
1 text_PUT FLAG HERE
2 text
3 text_PUT FLAG HERE
4 text
5 text
6 text_PUT FLAG HERE
7 text
8 text
9 text
10 text
11 text
12 text
13 text
14 text
15 text
16 text
17 text_PUT FLAG HERE
```

Done!

Yes, yes, awk is shorter<sup>1</sup>, faster and more beautiful.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Actually not, but still.</sub>

Another remark: the grep step is not actually required, see answers by potong and Walter A.

Comment: This doesnt work for me. My actual case is radically more complicated than the fake example I posted. BUT i'm unsure where the complication lies so that I can formulate the proper edit. Would this work if I just eliminated all space characters? And how would you remake this to work in that case? I think the spaces I added in my original example may have made this much simpler than it should be, and thus the code you posted does not match the operation Im really doing

Comment: @Tom If you simplify your example such that a solution to the example doesn't solve the original problem, then you've simplified too much ;) What exactly do you mean by "eliminate all space characters"? Which space characters? Mind you that Walter A's solution basically does the same, but more direct.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

you don't need other tools with the full power of awk at your disposal

```
$ awk -v tag='_PUT FLAG HERE' 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}
                              {print $0 ($1 in a?tag:"")}' pattern file 

1 text_PUT FLAG HERE                                                       
2 text
3 text_PUT FLAG HERE
4 text
5 text
```

just as an exercise, do the same with join/sort

```
$ sort <(join pattern file --nocheck-order | 
         sed 's/$/_PUT_FLAG_HERE/') <(join -v2 pattern file --nocheck-order)

1 text_PUT_FLAG_HERE
2 text
3 text_PUT_FLAG_HERE
4 text
5 text
```

perhaps defining function for DRY

```
$ f() { join $1 pattern file --nocheck-order; }; sort <(f "" | 
                         sed 's/$/_PUT_FLAG_HERE/') <(f -v2)
```

Comment: I'm consistently amazed as to what `awk` can do. Lets give this a shot

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
**pattern.txt:**

```
1
3
6
17
```

**file.txt:**

```
1 text
2 text
3 text
4 text
5 text
```

Use awk:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR{seen[$1];next} $1 in seen{printf("%s_PUT FLAG HERE\n",$0);next}1' pattern.txt file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
1 text_PUT FLAG HERE
2 text
3 text_PUT FLAG HERE
4 text
5 text
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution of @Benjamin can be simplified to

```
sed -f <(sed 's#.*#/^& /s/$/_PUT FLAG HERE/#' pattern.txt) file.txt
```

Explanation

```
# Read awk commands from a file
    sed -f awkcommands.txt pattern.txt file.txt

# Read awk commands from other command
    sed -f <(other_command) file.txt

# Append string to every line by replacing end-of-line character $
    sed 's/$/_PUT FLAG HERE/'

# Only append string on lines matching something
    sed '/something/s/$/_PUT FLAG HERE/#'

# Only append string on lines matching something at the beginning of the line followed by a space
    sed '/^something /s/$/_PUT FLAG HERE/#'

# Get the word something in above command selecting the whole line with .* and putting it in the new sed command with &.
# The slashes are used for the inner sed command, so use # here
    sed 's#.*#/^& /s/$/_PUT FLAG HERE/#' pattern.txt

# Now all together:
    sed -f <(sed 's#.*#/^& /s/$/_PUT FLAG HERE/#' pattern.txt) file.txt
```

Comment: Good point - wouldn't that have been more appropriate as a comment?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Good point too - I first tried something without your code and optimised my solution with parts of yours. I thought you deserved the credits, so thats why I mentioned you. I wasnt sure that you would edit your answer and I wanted to show an alternative for the powerful awk.

Comment: I'm always for showing a sed alternative to awk, just because ;) I've not updated my answer now, as that would make for duplicate content - just mentioning yours as well now.

Comment: I'm having some major issues comprehending all the symbols that are going on here. Can you deconvolute what each one means?

Comment: This didn't work. The example I had was probably too simple. The pattern may not always be a number. And the file.txt may have complicated strings surrounding each line. Like 
    1_other text\n

    leadingtext+_2_othertext\n

    3\n

    4text
(I can't put newline in comments for some reason, but imagine those things with newlines.

Comment: I assumed that the fields in pattern.txt should be at the start of the line (that's my `^`-character) and must be followed by a space for a match. Should pattern `6` match `16 text`  and `61 text` ? I tried to avoid this, and that's why it works different (better/worse?) then @potong.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses only Bash (4.0+) features:

```
# Set up associative array 'patterns' whose keys are patterns
declare -A patterns
for pat in $(< pattern.txt) ; do patterns[$pat]=1 ; done

# Slurp all the lines of 'file.txt' into the 'lines' array
readarray -t lines < file.txt

# Write each old line in the file, possibly with a suffix, back to the file
for line in "${lines[@]}" ; do
    read -r label text <<< "$line"
    printf '%s%s\n' "$line" "${patterns[$label]+_PUT FLAG HERE}"
done > file.txt
```

NOTES:

1. The changes are written back to 'file.txt', as the question seems to specify.
2. Bash 4.0 or later is required for associative arrays and `readarray`.
3. Bash is very slow, so this solution may not be practical if either of the files is large (more than 10 thousand lines).